# How to call a forth function from within assembler created through forth

Tags: assembly, forth, vfxforth

If I create a forth word that simply calls `.`, I can see that it looks like this

```
: mytest . ;
see mytest
MYTEST 
( 0010D7B0    E8BB70F1FF )            CALL    00024870  .
( 0010D7B5    C3 )                    RET/NEXT
( 6 bytes, 2 instructions )
```

But I'm struggling to use `CODE` and `END-CODE` to do the same thing.

If I write forth code like this:

```
CODE mytest2
CALL    00024870  .
NEXT, 
END-CODE
```

and try to include it at the command line, I get

```
Err# -4 ERR: Data stack underflow.
 Source: "/Users/xxx/scratch/forth/test1.fth" on line 3 
 -> NEXT, 
         ^
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

Is there any way for me to use forth to create words using assembler, in which I can call forth functions? Maybe I just have the wrong syntax, or maybe it's not possible?

This is VfxForth, x86_64, linux

Many thanks!

EDIT: Ah! I got it to work!
The problem was that the address `00024870` of the function to call is in hex. It shows up disassembled in a format that would suggest it is decimal. So it worked when I did:

```
CODE mytest2
CALL 0x00024870
NEXT,
END-CODE
```

and when mytest2 is disassembled, I get what I was looking for:

```
see mytest2
MYTEST2 
( 0010D9B0    E8BB6EF1FF )            CALL    00024870  .
( 0010D9B5    C3 )                    RET/NEXT
```

Comment: The question is specific and cannot be answered in general. Better to change the formulation to not include the answer, and add that it applies to vfxforth.

Answer (score 2):

Just posting up my own answer to help anyone else that may stumble on this.

The problem was that the address `00024870` of the function to call is in hex. It shows up disassembled in a format that would suggest it is decimal. So it worked when I made `00024870` overtly hex with `0x00024870`:

```
CODE mytest2
CALL 0x00024870
NEXT,
END-CODE
```

and when mytest2 is disassembled, I get what I was looking for:

```
see mytest2
MYTEST2 
( 0010D9B0    E8BB6EF1FF )            CALL    00024870  .
( 0010D9B5    C3 )                    RET/NEXT
```

Also, note that the `.` at the end of the `CALL` statement is not legal assembly. Rather the disassembler (sort of) helpfully adds the forth name of the function that the address maps to. So if instead I was calling `.S` to look at the stack, it would put `.S` there.